# PTC WindChill how to get started?

Tags: ptc-windchill

I want some recommendations on things to read, tutorials, etc on PTC WindChill.

And know your opinion about them.

Also I'd like you to tell about any tricky problems or things or common pitfalls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what you intend to do.

WindChill is a huge system made of several components (a PDM database, an application server, the Info*Engine web framework, etc.), so you must first have a basic idea of what you want to be able to do with it (try to get some use cases for example).

Then, since it is a proprietary system targeted towards a really specific market (PLM), the best way to get started is to get a training course directly from PTC or one of their local partners.

That's what I've done, and I was pretty pleased to learn that I needed to know a really small fraction of the whole system to get things done for my needs, using just a few HTTP GET requests.

Comment: Guess that my question can not be answered "better", because WindChill is such a huge being? I'll start my work in 1,5 months, so I wanted to prepare, somehow... but it seems, that it is not possible without further info. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Since the WindChill documentation and resources are not freely available, without more information it will be difficult to prepare. It is like saying "How to get started with SAP?". Not easy! But I'm sure you will find your way when you'll start your work. Good luck!

Comment: That's the truth for sure Gabriel.  I have been working heavily with a subset of windchill components for the last few months, and it is one of those systems that can be easily introduced in concept, but to get down and fully understand the whole thing would take years.

Answer (score 2):

You can also look into these [tutorials](http://learningexchange.ptc.com/tutorials/by_product/product_id:2)

Comment: Please give a bit of detail what the link says about the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to PLM, the PTC Training classes are useful (they have self-guided training as well that introduces the concepts of product data management: http://www.ptc.com/products/ptc-university/). Best of luck!